# Check If Folder Exists Is Not Working

Tags: php, function, wordpress, directory

I'm trying to get this function to recognize if a folder exists on the server, but it's not working. I've tried is_dir function as well but no luck.

This script is trying to be utilized in a Wordpress plugin, but it's using the php-based function to look if a file/folder exists. Any idea why it's not recognizing that the /docs folder exists? I've verified that $filename is actually pulling up the correct file path on server.

```
function docs_settings_page() {
    $filename = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/docs/";
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "The folder exists!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry - the file does not exist.";
    }
}

function docs_create_menu() {
    // Do stuff here
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'docs_create_menu');
```

Comment: see if error reporting throws anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Nope - no php errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function returns the URI of the document.
In your case you would need the absolute path, not the URI.

*Clarification:*
**URI:** The thing you type into your browser.
**Absolute Path:** The path from the root directory of your webspace / server.

So to get your 'docs' folder inside your theme's directory you would do
`$path = get_template_directory()."/docs/"`

I hope this helped,
Sebastian

Comment: Hey Sebastian. This returns the path to parent theme. The equivalent for child theme is $filename = get_stylesheet_directory()."/docs/"; . Tried that but no luck.

Comment: Ah, you need the child themes path?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add that in initial question. But while the child directory path is correct now with the code snippet I provided above, the file_exists function isn't returning true.

Comment: Hm... Don't know what that's about... Sorry.

Comment: After utilizing the $filename = get_stylesheet_directory()."/docs/"; modification to your suggestion and works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns a relative path for web-view, but `file_exists(...)` doesn't work with web-view, it uses the physical location of the directory on the server. Thus you need to use [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) to first get the physical path of your wordpress directory, then you can add the reference to the stylesheet directory, etc.

Try: `$filename=get_home_path().get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/docs/";`

Comment: Tried your snippet but no luck. I used this updated code to get the path on server, but still no luck in getting the statement to return true:

$filename = get_stylesheet_directory()."/docs/";

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ultimater's and Sebastian's help, this condition resolved my issue with a Wordpress child theme:

```
$filename = get_stylesheet_directory()."/docs/";
if(file_exists($filename)) { ... }
```